# não consigo com Number,emiti o texto na tela

Tags: javascript, html5, html-tags, textbox

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', calcular)

function calcular() {
  peso = document.getElementById('peso').value
  peso = peso.replace(",", ".")
  peso = Number(peso)
  altura = document.querySelector('#altura').value
  altura = altura.replace(',', '.')
  altura = Number(altura)
  res = document.getElementById('res').value = (peso / (altura ** 2)).toFixed(2)
  if (peso == '' || altura == '') {
    alert('[Erro],Precisa inseri todos os campos!')
  } else if (res > 0 && res < 18.5) {
    alert(res)
    //não está mostrando o resultado na tela
    res.innerHTML = res
    res.innerHTML += res.toString()
    document.body.style.background = 'yellow'
  } else if (res < 24.9) {
    alert('oikkkk')

    document.body.style.background = 'black'
  } else if (res < 29.9) {
    alert('oi')
    //mesmo informando o res não mostra nada
    res.innerText += 'oi'
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Imc</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>IMC</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div>
        <p>Vamos calcular o imc
          <button>calcular</button>
        </p>

        <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" placeholder="  Exe: 95, 74.5, 30,2"> Digite seu peso
        <input type="text" name="altura" id="altura" placeholder="  Exe: 1.80 , 1.7 , 2,02"> Digite sua altura
      </div>
      <div id="res" align='center'>
        Seu resultado...
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Coloquei o `Number` pois queria usa qualquer numero mesmo com virgula, mas consegui tive que passa o replace().
   Sem `Number` não consigo mostra o erro se não forem indicado tanto o peso ou altura ,para usa o `parsefloat` tem que passa `eval()` para mostra o erro ou informa .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu dei uma ajeitada na disposição do HTML só para deixar a visualização do problema mais fácil.

O principal problema que vi foi nessa linha:

```
res = document.getElementById('res').value = (peso / (altura ** 2)).toFixed(2)
```

Sua intenção parece ser referenciar um elemento HTML e ao mesmo tempo fazer uso de uma de suas propriedades, no caso `value`. Não e possível fazer isso numa só instrução.

Primeiro referencie o objeto e a partir da referência manipule as propriedades, por exemplo:

```
//Primeiro obtém a referência.
res = document.getElementById('res')
//Depois atribui uma valor a uma de suas propriedades.
res.value = parseFloat(peso / (altura ** 2))
```

No caso para converter as string em número usei a função [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) que analisa um argumento e retorna número de ponto flutuante.

Só usei o método [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) somente na exibição do IMC pois esse método retorna uma string representando o número usando notação em ponto fixo.

Também troquei os aninhamentos de `ifs` por [operadores condicionais ternários](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Condicional).

Finalmente para exibir o resultado do calculo na tela usei a propriedade [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText)

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', calcular)

function calcular() {
  peso = document.getElementById('peso').value
  altura = document.querySelector('#altura').value
  //res é referência para o div cujo o id='res'
  res = document.getElementById('res')
  //Trata as entradas e converte para float
  peso = parseFloat(peso.replace(",", "."))
  altura = parseFloat(altura.replace(',', '.'))
  //Verifica se dados são válidos
  if (isNaN(peso) || isNaN(altura)) {
    res.innerText = 'Precisa preecher os campos com valores numéricos!'
    return
  }
  //Calcula o IMC
  imc = peso / (altura ** 2)

  //Cria uma uma mensagem de acordo com o IMC.
  msg = imc > 0 && imc < 18.5 ? 'abaixo do peso':
                   imc < 24.9 ? 'com o peso normal':
                   imc < 29.9 ? 'com sobrepeso' :
                   imc < 34.9 ? 'com obesidade grau 1':
                   imc < 39.9 ? 'com obesidade grau 2':
                                'com obesidade grau 3'
                                
  //Exibe o IMC no HTML com uma mensagem personalizada.
  res.textContent = `Seu IMC é ${imc.toFixed(2)} e você está ${msg}.`                         
                          

}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Imc</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>IMC</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h5>Vamos calcular o seu IMC:</h5>
      <label>Digite seu peso
        <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" placeholder="  Exe: 95, 74.5, 30,2"> 
       </label>
      <label> Digite sua altura
        <input type="text" name="altura" id="altura" placeholder="  Exe: 1.80 , 1.7 , 2,02"> 
       </label>
    </section>
    <br><button>calcular</button><br><br>
    <section>
      <span id="res" align='center'>          
      </span>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @EvertonCostaSouza, sim pode fazer, vai ficar legal. É só atribuir a classe ao elemento de acordo com o IMC, basta usar o método [`Element.classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: vou tentar fazer e vê se consigo vc percebeu que entendo pouco de javascript kkkkk, e muito obrigado .

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que sua variável "res" esta com o valor do resultado do calculo "(peso / (altura ** 2)).toFixed(2)" e não com o elemento do dom desejado, por conta disso res.innerHTML não funciona.

Tente armazenar o elemento do dom em uma variável separada e depois altere seu conteúdo.

```
resultado = (peso / (altura ** 2)).toFixed(2);
elemento = document.getElementById('res');
elemento.innerHTML = resultado;
```

Comment: conseguir, fiz o que você me sugeriu e também mudei outra maneira de declara métodos e objetos,muito obrigado.